# How to get rid of unwanted space in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable called `trouble_maker`. Some observations have more than hundred unnecessary space before it, such as`__________abc`. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the space before the first character please.

Comment: Google is a more appropriate site for this kind of question.  You could have literally taken part of your question "how to get rid of the space" and typed "SAS" in front of it, and found your answer.  Please do your own research first before asking other people to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of leading spaces before your string: `left(trouble_maker);` (the one you need)

To get rid of trailing spaces after your string: `trim(trouble_maker);`

To get rid of consecutive spaces within your string: `compbl(trouble_maker);`

To get rid of all spaces in your string: `compress(trouble_maker);`

Comment: For getting rid of leading *and* training blanks - `cats` or `strip`.